# Likelihood over a arbitrary set of hypotheses

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, markov-process, likelihood, estimators

I have the following issue.  I have finite, large, enumerated set $H$ of hypotheses that maps a time series to an integer, let's say days to integers i.e. $H \subseteq (\mathrm{Day} \to \mathbb{N})$.  I now have another hypothesis $e:\mathrm{Day}\to\mathbb N$ that I want to match.  A.k.a. I want to find the $h \in H$ that is the most probable given the evidence $e$ a.k.a. $\mathrm{argmax}_{h\in H} P(h|e)$.

Using bayes' rule I convert this probability to $P(e|h)\cdot P(h)$ where $P(h)$ is constant if we assume any hypothesis is initially as likely to be selected.

Next, I try to compute $P\big(e(a)\big|h(a)\big)$ for given $h\in H$, $a\in \mathrm{Day}$ and $e(a),h(a) \in \mathbb N$.  I have no idea what estimator I should use here.

After that, I was to compute $P(e|h)$ for each $h \in H$ and find the maximizing $h$, where
$$
P(e|h) = \prod_{a\in\mathrm{Day}} P\Big(e(a)\Big|h(a)\Big)
$$

I feel a bit wacky in my reasoning.  Could you show me any weaknesses in it?  Also, what should I use to get $P\big(e(a)\big|h(a)\big)$?

Thank you for reading and helping!

Comment: The notations are unclear: is $H$ a set of integers $\{1,2,..,K\}$ that label models under comparison? and what is $h(a)$ supposed to mean?

Comment: $H$ is a set of functions $h : \mathrm{Day} \to \mathbb{N}$, like $e$.  Those function themselves are the given "models", though not a very probabilistic version of it.

Comment: But what should I use to get $P\big(e(a)\big|h(a)\big)$?  A gaussian $\mathcal{N}( h(a), \text{something} )$ evaluated at $e(a)$ ?

Comment: There is no answer to this question: your model needs to be specified jointly in $e$ and $h$ to become a fully Bayesian model. The distribution on the observables $e$ [I assume they are observable] is deduced from your settings, there is no default choice for a sampling distribution!

Comment: The issue I have, is that I have only one evidence $e$, which is not really an observable, but rather some user assumption to match.  Thus I "have only one sample" for $e$, that given user assumption.  What distribution should I use for a single-sampled $e$?

Comment: I am afraid there is no default solution. You can always try with a Gaussian with fixed variance (ie not depending on a and maybe not depending on h).

Comment: I was afraid that was the only solution.  I wanted to make sure I didn't miss any smart way to solve the problem.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: But this is not the only solution: any distribution that does make sense for this "data" can be used as well. With different outcomes, of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31184/discussion-between-laerne-and-xian).